# Python Imaging Library iterating through an array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm writing a program, and one of the features of the program requires me to generate an image. I currently have an array, and want Python Imaging Library to iterate through the array and create an image, in png/jpeg format with a 1 being black and 0 being white. Thank you for any responses.

Comment: Hello! While rendering images dynamically might be an interesting topic, it will be hard to find the correct answer to your solution. You can edit your question any time, so feel free to add some code to help other readers to get an idea about what you're trying to do.

Comment: so you image will be one pixel high and len(array) pixels wide?

Comment: How is your array ? is it a `numpy` array ? you can use `matplotlib` to save it as an image or PyPNG : https://github.com/drj11/pypng/ ... please most more details

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have an NxN array with 0's and 1's that needs to be saved as an image using PIL.

Image generated from this solution is very basic to demonstrate concept. You can research to take it to next level.

Since we don't have your exact array , First we create an array of size NxN filled with randomly generated 1's and 0's.

```
N = 128
myarray = np.random.randint(2, size=(N, N))
```

Next we cast array to `dtype` of `np.uint8`

```
myarray = np.asarray(myarray, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Here is array generated from above.

> > > myarray
> >
> > array([[0, 1, 0, ..., 1, 0, 1],
> >            [1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
> >            [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
> >            ..., 
> >            [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
> >            [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
> >            [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0]], dtype=uint8)

Next we create image object from array

```
myimage = Image.fromarray(myarray, mode='1') #mode 1 for B&W
```

Next, save image to `png`.

```
myimage.save("out.png")
```

**Generated Image**

[image]